# How to add a variable with mutate for selected rows at fixed interval

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset, which contains a text with many related values. The text is distributed 1 word per row. Each word has a ID, which identifies its position in the text. I want to add a variable called "Line", where I add a value to every 10 words, so that the first ten (1:10) will then have Line = 1, 11-20 will have Line = 2, and so on.
It's a really long text, so I don't want to have to manually write the mutate function for every ten words.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Here is what the interested variables look like

```
structure(list(IA_LABEL = c("it", "is", "a", "triumph", "said", 
"mr", "bankes", "laying", "his", "knife", "down", "for", "a", 
"moment", "he", "had", "eaten", "attentively", "it", "is", "rich", 
"it", "is", "tender", "it", "is", "perfectly", "cooked", "he", 
"thought"), Item_ID = 1:30), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use `gl` in creating a grouping indicator

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Line = as.integer(gl(n(), 10, n())))
```

---

Or use `%/%`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(Line = (row_number() - 1) %/% 10 + 1)
```